# Capital and non-capital citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am writing a small paper and I have to use two types of citations throughout the text.

The first one is 1)"(AUTHOR,Year)" and the second one is 2)"Author(Year)", while at the same time I am using, in the bibliography, apa style, so that it prints "Last Name, Initials (year). Title. etc".

I managed to succesfuly use only one of the citations styles (1 or 2) AND the bibliography, but I can't manage to use all three. I saw some solutions but they only used either all capital citations and a given type of bibliography style or, the other way around, non-capital citations and a given type of bibliography style.

I am using Mendeley to write my .bib file, Windows 8.1 and TexMaker.

Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,style=apa,maxbibnames=99,maxalphanames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/Andre/Documents/Bibtex/library.bib}

\begin{document}


This should be the first type of citation "(AUTHOR et al.,Year)" but what I get is:\\ \citep{Alsina2017} \\
and this should be the second type of citation "Author et al.(Year)" and I sucessfuly get this:\\
\citet{Alsina2017} .


\newpage


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want all parenthesized citations (using `\parencite`) to capitalize the author names?

Comment: I think it actually makes no difference since I will only use these two types of citations. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a reasonably recent `biblatex` the following works

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifdefstring{\blx@delimcontext}{parencite}
    {\textsc{#1}}
    {#1}}
\makeatother
```

This checks if we are in a `\parencite` and if so, prints the name in small caps. All other names are left as is.

Comment: Very nice. You might want to add this answer to this question too: [biblatex: uppercase in \parencite, but not in \textcite](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/101649).

Comment: It works, buut, it cites all authors instead of using "et al."

Comment: @AndréPadilha The 'et al.' is normally controlled by the option `maxcitenames`, but that does not work with`style=apa`. The APA style has special rules about 'et al.' that `style=apa` implements to the letter.

Comment: Got it. And what would be a good style to achieve alphabetically ordered bibliography?

Comment: @AndréPadilha `style=authoryear` (maybe with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`)? It depends on what exactly you want. But you really should only use `style=apa` if you *must* follow the APA style. For ABNT freaks (shudder) there is https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt

Comment: Thank you sooo much! How do you know so much about latex?